# Trouble triggering reactivity on changed Vuex objects

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm modifying the value of an existing property on an object that is in an array of objects in my Vuex.store. When I update the store, it is not triggering a re-render of my computed property that is accessing the store. If I reset the stored value to an empty array, and then set it again to my new array, it'll trigger the change. But simply updating the property of the array of objects does not trigger a change.

I have tried using `Vue.set()` [like the docs talk about](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vues-reactivity-rules), and that updates the store, but still does not trigger a re-render of the computed property. What am I missing? Using Vue 2.2.4 and Vuex 2.2.0.

```
//DEBUG: An example of the updated post I'm adding
let myNewScheduledPost = {
    id: 1,
    name: 'James'
};
this.$store.dispatch('addScheduledPost', post);

//DEBUG: My store
const options = {
    state: {
        scheduledPosts: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Jimmy'}
        ],
    },
    mutations: {
        scheduledPosts: (state, scheduledPosts) => {
            //This triggers the reactivity/change so my computed property re-renders
            //But of course seems the wrong way to do it.
            state.scheduledPosts = [];
            state.scheduledPosts = scheduledPosts;

            //Neither of these two lines triggers my computed property to re-render, even though there is a change in scheduledPosts
            state.scheduledPosts = scheduledPosts;
            Vue.set(state, 'scheduledPosts', scheduledPosts);
        },
    },
    actions: {
        addScheduledPost({ commit, getters }, newScheduledPost) {
            let scheduledPosts = getters.scheduledPosts;
            const idx = scheduledPosts.findIndex(existingScheduledPost => existingScheduledPost.id === newScheduledPost.id);

            //If the post is already in our list, update that post
            if (idx > -1) {
                scheduledPosts[idx] = newScheduledPost;
            } else {
                //Otherwise, create a new one
                scheduledPosts.push(newScheduledPost);
            }
            commit('scheduledPosts', scheduledPosts);

            //DEBUG: This DOES have the correct updated change - but my component does not see the change/reactivity.
            console.log(getters.scheduledPosts);
        }
    },
    getters: {
        scheduledPosts: (state) => {
            return state.scheduledPosts;
        }
    }
};

//DEBUG: Inside of my component
computed: {
    mySortedPosts()
    {
        console.log('im being re-rendered!');
        return this.$store.getters.scheduledPosts.sort(function() { 
            //my sorted function 
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is if you are wanting to access a portion of the state you don't use a getter https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/state.html.

```
computed: {
    mySortedPosts(){
        return this.$store.state.scheduledPosts
    }
}
```

Getters are for computed properties **in the store** https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html. So in your case you might create a getter to sort your scheduled posts then name it `sortedScheduledPosts` and then you can add it to your components computed properties like you are now.

The key thing is your getter needs to have a different name then your state property just like you would in a component.